# nano and vim (search) history remove

Tags: 22.04, vim, history, nano

How can I delete nano and vim history (typed text, search, etc.)? I don't want to disable it for the future, only erase the current values. THX

Comment: Have you enabled history for vi and nano. If yes then check file `~/.nano_history` for nano

Comment: Are you using a supported Ubuntu release?  Have you read `man nano vim`?